# Understanding the difference between types and representations

Tags: language-agnostic, type-theory

[This article](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/05/types-la-chart.html) speaks of the difference between types and classes. Since I've only worked with languages that treat both as identical, please suggest material/programming-languages that will teach me the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference is not the right word - classes are certainly types. But not all types are classes. Note also that the word "class" is quite vague - it could be just a tuple type (with no operations except construction and projection - a C struct so to speak) or, on the other side of the spectrum, a class that contains only methods, but no state.

Answer (score 1):

[Sather](http://www.gnu.org/software/sather/docs-1.2/tutorial/intro79.html#AEN132) is the oldest language i know of which treats types and classes separately. However, it is not completely rigorous, as one can still use a class as a variable type (i think), one just can't subtype it.

This is not terribly different from what C++ lets you do: you can use purely abstract classes to define types, and have all concrete classes implement them using public inheritance, but subclass each other using private inheritance. You then use the abstract classes for variable types, using the concrete classes only in constructor expressions.

Java lets you do more or less the same, defining types using interfaces and implementations using classes, but because there is no private inheritance, there is no way to hide the inheritance relationship of the classes.

Does that make any sense at all?

Comment: I don't understand what "private inheritance" actually means.

Comment: It means you inherit the implementation but not the interface. So if Foo privately extends Bar, you can't assign a pointer to Foo to a variable of type pointer-to-Bar. But Foo still gets all the code and fields from Bar. It's commonly used for mixins, to add some canned functionality to a class without leaving any trace in its type.

Answer (score 0):

Java, pre-autoboxing. `int` and `Integer` are both types, but only the latter is a class.